# How can I insert a widget into a mainwindow generated by Qt designer?

Tags: qt, nokia, qwidget

I have a Main window build with Qt Designer and I also have a widget built with Qt designer (both in a separate ui file).  How can I instantiate my widget into my mainwindow at runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way (using Designer) is to open your main window, drag a `QWidget` into it, and position/name the `QWidget` like you would your custom widget.  Once that is done, right-click on the `QWidget`, and select **Promote to...**.  A dialog will show up with the widgets it can be promoted to.  At the bottom of that dialog, you can add a new widget for promotion.  Type in the class name and include file information, and add that widget.  Then select the entry in the list, and click the **Promote** button.

At the end of this process, you should be able to recompile, and your custom widget will be where you placed it in the main window.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use [QMainWindow::setCentralWidget](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget) function?